# Is there any sense in which mesons could act as force carriers, in the way that gauge bosons do?

Tags: bosons, gauge, mesons

Gauge bosons are force carriers. Mesons are composite bosons and have similar characteristics to gauge bosons. Is there any sense in which mesons could act as force carriers?

Comment: Mesons act as intermediary force carriers for the strong interaction between nucleons, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mesons may participate in interactions completely analogous to gauge bosons in *effective field theories*.

One prominent example is the [pion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pion) in an effective quantum field theory on the level of nucleons, which appears as the force carrier of the force between nucleons in a Yukawa type interaction. In fact, Yukawa first predicted the existence of mesons because they would explain how the nuclear force arises (cf. the [history section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_force#History) of the Wikipedia article).

Comment: Ah, thank you very much for the details on that! :D